# Perl modifying hash in subroutine - global symbol requires explicit package name

Tags: perl, hash, reference

Having some trouble adding some keys to a hash, i.e. modifying in a subroutine. Here's my subroutine call:

```
getMissingItems($filename, \%myItems); #myItems is already defined above this
```

and the subroutine itself:

```
sub getMissingItems {
    my $filename = shift;
    my $itemHash = shift;

    #... some stuff

    foreach $item (@someItems) {

        if (not exists $itemHash{$item}) {
            %$itemHash{$item} = 0; 
        }

    }

}
```

I get the error "Global symbol %itemHash requires explicit package name"

How should I be doing this properly? Thanks.

EDIT - thanks everyone, over this first hurdle. I'm now getting "Can't use string ("0") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use." I just want to set the missing key entry to zero

Comment: The new error would only occur from the code you provided if you clobered `$itemhash` somewhere in the "...". Please provide a minimal, runnable demonstration of the problem. It's ok if you start a new question as it is unrelated to the one you already asked.

Comment: Actually I didn't use $itemHash before the inner loop posted. And, clobered?

Comment: I'm able to use "undef" and it seems to be doing the job since elsewhere in the script undef is converted to 0. But I'd be curious why this doesn't work, I thought I could deference and modify the hash (add keys, etc).

Comment: Somewhere in your file, you have `$itemsHash->{something}{somethingelse}`. If `$itemsHash->{something}` is `0`, that's the same thing as `0->{something}`.

Comment: I think that's what's happening, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `%itemHash` in scope of your sub, yet you try to use a variable named that.

You mean to access the hash referenced by `$itemHash`, so

```
if (not exists $itemHash{$item}) {
    %$itemHash{$item} = 0; 
}
```

should be

```
if (not exists $itemHash->{$item}) {
    $itemHash->{$item} = 0; 
}
```

---

By the way, you could simplify that to

```
$itemHash->{$item} //= 0;
```

(That checks if the element is `defined`, not if it `exists`, but that's probably the same thing in this case.)

Answer (score 3):

You're not using the correct syntax for accessing elements of a hashref.

Try `$itemhash->{$item}` or `$$itemhash{$item}` in the innermost loop.

Answer (score 1):

To acces a value in a hash reference, use the arrow dereference operator:

```
if (not exists $itemHash->{$item}) {
    $itemHash->{$item} = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The line `%$itemHash{$item} = 0;` should read `$itemHash->{$item} = 0;`. The version you have tries to do something different (and wrong). For help untangling references, I recommend reading the [Perl References Tutorial](http://p3rl.org/perlreftut).

Answer (score 1):

Your code has $itemHash{$item}, it should be $itemHash->{$item}.  The code below points to the line with the error.

```
sub getMissingItems {
    my $filename = shift;
    my $itemHash = shift;

    foreach $item (@someItems) {

        if (not exists $itemHash{$item}) { # <--- this is wrong
            %$itemHash{$item} = 0; # <--- this one too
        }

    }
}
```